# Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: android, build

Запускаю проект - все работает отлично. Меняю текст в `strings`, запускаю чтобы проверить - выдает ошибку:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\AutoDeep\Android Studio\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

И подчеркивает `R` при наведении высвечивает -> `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'`.

`Build -> Clean Project` не помогло. После очистки перезапуск тоже не помог. Запускаю проект до изменения текста в `string` - работает. Меняю текст -> перестает работать. Возвращаю текст в проект, который не работает - не помогает. Что это такое?

`File->InvalidateCahces` - также не помог.

Comment: Как выглядит strings.xml при ошибке?

Comment: он достаточно большой

Comment: Удалял части текста, чтобы вычислить ту, из-за чего ошибка. Вот:

   "<br><br><big><b><font color="maroon">Текст</font></b></big><br><br>
  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp ТекстТекстТекст <b><i>Текст</i></b> и <b><i>Текст</i></b>. ТекстТекстТекст <b><i>Текст</i></b>, ТекстТекстТекст.
  ТекстТекстТекст."

Если убрать этот абзац - все заработает. В чем проблема не пойму.

Comment: Я скрыл текст, но в нем есть два числа: "85%" и "15%".. так вот, если убрать % и сделать так: "85", а "15%" оставить - все работает. Если "%" вернуть к "85", то ошибка. Мистика.

Comment: Вставь, пожалуйста, кусок strings.xml с ошибкой без изменений в сам вопрос, я хочу помочь

Comment: Проблема решена. Дело было в процентах. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Tools → Android → Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Без результата. Дальнейший перезапуск также не дал изменений.

Comment: А что именно вы меняете в strings?

Comment: Между: <string name="txt_1"><![CDATA[ и ]]></string> пишу текст. Например, было написано: "Привет" все работало. Написал "Привет, тра та та" - перестало работать.

Comment: Я несколько озадачен тем, что вы заворачиваете простой текст вроде "Привет, тра та та" в CDATA, а в остальном мистика, судя по описанию.

Comment: Согласен. Между <string name="txt_1"> и </string> Получается ещё один тег

Comment: Я в качестве примера. Хорошо. Вот:

&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<b><i>Какой-то текст</i></b><br> ну вроде этого. Теги поддерживаются. Новые не вводились.

Comment: Похоже проблема решена. В тексте есть два числа: "85%" и "15%".. так вот, если убрать % и сделать так: "85", а "15%" оставить - все работает. Если "%" вернуть к "85", то ошибка. Мистика

Comment: Да, есть такая проблема. Необходимо или удваивать второй символ процента или использовать вместо символа процента его код `\u0025`.